# How to embed swf in Eclipse - Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, flash

I'm doing an application using Eclipse Juno 4.2.1 and I want to import an swf file for some animations. Is it possible to embed and use it without using WebView? I've tried using the WebView process but all it display is a white blank page . Is there any other way around, an example source code would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried that too, but in my experience its better to cut swf into frames and than recreate the animation timeline with xml. If the animation is big however, its probably not the best solution. I was investigating this problem like year ago and haven't found any useful solution, other than, what I have wrote.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but may I ask if there are any other flash builder or anything animation builder that I can use in Android Eclipse any kind of file extension will do. :D

Comment: For this you are going to have to need a Flash Professional. Where you can easily save frames as pictures. You could probably do that by code in Flash Builder too, but I haven't done anything in AS3 for like 2 years, so I am not going to be much of a help here : (